# abstract class and virtual functions

Tags: c++, abstract-class

Would this class be considered an abstract class because it has one virtual function? I was still able to create an Animal object and call getFoodCost();

I thought abstract classes cannot be instantiated.  Does this mean objects can have virtual functions and not be considered abstract class?

```
class Animal
{
public:
    Animal();
    int getBabies();
    double getFoodCost();
    virtual double getPayOff();
    int getQty();

    void incAge();
    void setAge(int);

protected:
    int counter=0;
    int age;
    int cost;   
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Would this class be considered an abstract class because it has one virtual function? I was still able to create an Animal object and call getFoodCost();

No. In C++, "Abstract Class" usually refers to a class with a [pure virtual function](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pure-virtual-functions-and-abstract-classes/):

```
class Abstract {
public:
    virtual void PureVirtual() = 0; // no implementation
};

class NotAbstract {
    virtual void NotPureVirutal() {
        // Some implementation
    }
};
```

> I thought abstract classes cannot be instantiated.

Yes, that is correct. This is because abstract classes have functions with no required implementation. It has no way to instantiate an instance directly. It uses inheritance and pointers/references to refer to an abstract class.

> Does this mean objects can have virtual functions and not be considered abstract class?

Yes. Again, abstract classes are classes that have pure virtual functions. This is different from a regular virtual function. As discussed above, pure virtual functions have no required implementation. Regular virtual functions, on the other hand, are required to have an implementation associated with them, so they can be instantiated.

Comment: I know that is is kind of weird, but pure virtual functions *can* have implementations in C++. They are just *not required* and in most cases useless. In the case of pure virtual destructors, the pure virtual function even *must* be implemented.

Comment: So perhaps is it better to say "no useful implementation"?

Comment: I would go with "no required implementation", because the point of making a virtual member function pure virtual is either that you don't want to provide an implementation for it or that you want to explicitly make the class abstract, so that instances can't be created. A non-pure `virtual` function would need to be implemented.

Comment: @walnut From the C++20 standard: "A pure virtual function need be defined only if called with, or as if with, the qualified-id syntax".  The "as if with" part covers destructors.  So pure virtual functions need to be defined when they can directly called, like with `Abstract::PureVirtual()` from within a `NotAbstract` member function.

Comment: Is there a special term for the class Animal or is it just a normal class with 1 virtual function?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I am not sure what part of my comment you are referring to. Do you mean that "*in most cases useless*" is too strongly worded?

Comment: @leon I think it's called a "Virtual Class," but I can't find that somewhere to confirm. I'm especially hesitant to call it that because that name could be associated with something called "virtual inheritance," which is another thing entirely. Alternatively, your suggestion of, "a normal class with a virtual function" would probably work :D

Comment: @walnut The _kind of weird, but pure virtual functions can have implementations_ part.  It's not so weird, as just a specific set of conditions where implementations are required.

Comment: @leon A class with at least one virtual function would technically be called *polymorphic class* in C++. If you want to emphasize that it is not an abstract class, I guess *non-abstract polymorphic class* would be fine.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Yes sure it makes sense in the language, but I guess the usual idea in the OOP sense is that an abstract method is one that doesn't have an implementation, so going of that the behavior in C++ would be weird. In any case, yes, they are useful because they can be called via qualified-id and that sometimes is helpful.

Answer (score 3):

An abstract function is a `virtual` member function for which you do `= 0`, as in

```
virtual double getPayOff() = 0;
```

A class with at least one abstract function, including inherited ones, is an abstract class. A class with *only* pure virtual functions is a so-called *pure* abstract class (also known as an *interface* class).

Since your `getPayOff` function isn't pure virtual, your class isn't abstract either.

Comment: Does the standard actually define the "Pure abstract class" term?